# WebGrid: GetSelectLink() returning wrong details for selected record

Tags: c#, razor, webmatrix, webgrid

**Context**: I’m building a web application using WebMatrix and C# Razor. The application searches a database and returns the results to a WebGrid. Once the results are returned, you can click a Details link and view the details on a new browser tab.

**Problem**: The initial search, which returns all records, works fine. If I enter search words, the correct results are returned, but when I click on Details, I get details for the record that was in the selected row in the initial search.

**Example**: The initial search returns records 1-5. The subsequent search returns records 31, 65, 86,92, 101. If I click on Details for record 65, I get details for record 2 because record 2 occupied row 2 in the initial search.

**Code**:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "Home Page";
}
@{       
        var db = Database.Open("xyz");
        var query = "select bg_bug_id [BUGID], BG_SUMMARY SUMMARY from [dbo].[BUG] where BG_SUMMARY like @0 and BG_SUMMARY like @1";
        var input1 = "%" + Request["input1"] + "%";
        var input2 = "%" + Request["input2"] + "%";
        var data = db.Query(query, input1, input2);       
        var gridBug = new WebGrid(source: data, canPage: true, canSort: true, rowsPerPage: 10); 

      if(gridBug.HasSelection){        

        var recordIdInt = 0;
        recordIdInt = gridBug.SelectedRow.Value.BUGID;          
        var recordId = recordIdInt.ToString(); 

        var bugDescQuery = "select [BG_DESCRIPTION] from [dbo].[BUG] where [BG_BUG_ID] =" + recordId;  // or [BG_BUG_ID] = 25001";
        var bugDescResult = db.Query(bugDescQuery);     

        foreach(var item in bugDescResult){
            var desc = item.BG_DESCRIPTION;

            var modDesc = desc.Replace("<div align=\"left\">", "<div>").Replace("<font face=\"Arial\">", "<font>").Replace("<span style=\"font-size:8pt\">", "<span>");                                    


        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){                              

            var x = '@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(modDesc))';
            var win = window.open();            
            win.document.body.innerHTML = "Record ID: " + @recordId + " -   -" + x;

            })

        </script>                 

        }        
}
}              

<form method="post">

    <input type="text" name="input1"/>  

    <input type="radio" id="and" name="operator" value="and" checked>And
    <input type="radio" id="or" name="operator" value="or">Or    

    <input type="text" name="input2" />    

    <select>
    <option value="Unresolved">Unresolved</option>
    <option value="Resolved">Resolved</option>   
    </select>   

    <input type="submit" value="Search" />   

        @gridBug.GetHtml(
            tableStyle: "grid",
            headerStyle: "head",
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
            columns: gridBug.Columns(
            gridBug.Column(header:"", format:@<text>@item.GetSelectLink("Details")</text>, style: "product2"),
            gridBug.Column("BUGID", "BUGID", style: "product2"),
            gridBug.Column("SUMMARY", "SUMMARY", style: "product")))          

</form>
@section script{
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
        $('th a, tfoot a').live('click', function() {
            $('form').attr('action', $(this).attr('href')).submit();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
} 

 <style type="text/css">
            .grid {
                margin: 4px;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 950px;
                margin-left: 5px
            }
            .head {
                background-color: #0094ff;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #fff;
            }
            .grid th, .grid td {
                border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
                padding: 5px;
            }
            .alt {
                background-color: #e8e8e8;
                color: #000;
            }
            .product {
                width: 200px;
                font-weight: normal;
            }
            .product2 {
                width: 10px;
                font-weight: normal;                
            }              
        </style>
```

**SOURCE AFTER 2nd SEARCH:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Home Page</title>
        <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
        $('th a, tfoot a').live('click', function() {
            $('form').attr('action', $(this).attr('href')).submit();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="site-title"><a href="/">XXXX</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </section>
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li><a href="/">XXXX</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/About">XXXX</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Contact">XXXX</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">

            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">






<form method="post">

    <input type="text" name="input1"/>  

    <input type="radio" id="and" name="operator" value="and" checked>And
    <input type="radio" id="or" name="operator" value="or">Or    

    <input type="text" name="input2" />    

    <select>
    <option value="Unresolved">Unresolved</option>
    <option value="Resolved">Resolved</option>   
    </select>   

    <input type="submit" value="Search" />   

            <table class="grid">
    <thead>
        <tr class="head">
            <th scope="col">
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
<a href="/?sort=BUGID&amp;sortdir=ASC">BUGID</a>            </th>
            <th scope="col">
<a href="/?sort=SUMMARY&amp;sortdir=ASC">SUMMARY</a>            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr >
            <td colspan="3">1 <a href="/?page=2">2</a> <a href="/?page=3">3</a> <a href="/?page=2">&gt;</a> </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="product2"><a href="/?row=1">Details</a></td>
            <td class="product2">1655</td>
            <td class="product">summary text for record 1655</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="alt">
            <td class="product2"><a href="/?row=2">Details</a></td>
            <td class="product2">2516</td>
            <td class="product">summary text for record 2516</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="product2"><a href="/?row=3">Details</a></td>
            <td class="product2">2639</td>
            <td class="product">summary text for record 2639</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="alt">
            <td class="product2"><a href="/?row=4">Details</a></td>
            <td class="product2">2643</td>
            <td class="product">summary text for record 2643</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="product2"><a href="/?row=5">Details</a></td>
            <td class="product2">3493</td>
            <td class="product">summary text for record 3493</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="alt">
            <td class="product2"><a href="/?row=6">Details</a></td>
            <td class="product2">3746</td>
            <td class="product">summary text for record 3746</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="product2"><a href="/?row=7">Details</a></td>
            <td class="product2">3864</td>
            <td class="product">summary text for record 3864</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="alt">
            <td class="product2"><a href="/?row=8">Details</a></td>
            <td class="product2">5172</td>
            <td class="product">summary text for record 5172</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="product2"><a href="/?row=9">Details</a></td>
            <td class="product2">7156</td>
            <td class="product">summary text for record 7156</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="alt">
            <td class="product2"><a href="/?row=10">Details</a></td>
            <td class="product2">7532</td>
            <td class="product">summary text for record 7532</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>


</form>



 <style type="text/css">
            .grid {
                margin: 4px;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 950px;
                margin-left: 5px
            }
            .head {
                background-color: #0094ff;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #fff;
            }
            .grid th, .grid td {
                border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
                padding: 5px;
            }
            .alt {
                background-color: #e8e8e8;
                color: #000;
            }
            .product {
                width: 200px;
                font-weight: normal;
            }
            .product2 {
                width: 10px;
                font-weight: normal;                
            }              
        </style>



            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>&copy; 2015 - XXXX</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the markup of the search results after the search is performed that displays records 31, 65, 86,92, 101? It sounds like you're not writing out the ID's that you think you are when you're building the grid.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! Markup added to post. By the way, the record IDs 1-5 and 31,35,86,92,101 were for example only; actual IDs are different. Was trying to simplify for the example. I also had to mask some values in the source for confidentiality. You'll see XXXX in some places and 'summary text for [ID]'. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you show the code for function: @item.GetSelectLink("Details") ?? This is where your problem lies, as you can see from the markup you've provided that you querystring parameters have the row=ID# for the original search.

Comment: GetSelectLink() is a built-in method. If there's a way to view the code (in WebMatrix), I'm not aware of it. It seems that when I click Details, it refreshes the page, returning the original results, before it looks for the recordId. Maybe I need to prevent the refresh somehow, so that it grabs the recordId for the latest search results?